# MDX report rendering slow

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

This is my MDX query:

```
with member [Measures].[Rent] as IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Budget]), NULL, [Measures].[Rent])

select {[Measures].[Rent]} on columns,

          [Property].[Address].[All].children *
         DESCENDANTS([Account].[Account Hierarchy].[Account Group].[Expenditures],
                     [Account].[Account Tree].[Account]) *
                     [Asset].[asset].[All].children on rows
from    [Master]
```

When I comment the `[Asset] Dimension` member, I get the result, but I need Asset Dimension in MDX.

Does anyone have an idea on what to do??

Comment: Without seeing the cube details, this is difficult. Maybe http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966527.aspx can help you?

Answer (score 0):

You should try filtering dimensions before crossjoining them. In your case, if budget is null, just leave it. Also don't forget to add NON EMPTY clause to remove empty values from result set:

```
with 
     member hasBudget as
(
  IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Budget]), 0, 1)
)

member [Rent] as IIF(IsEmpty([Measures].[Budget]), NULL, [Measures].[Rent])
set accounts = Filter(DESCENDANTS([Account].[Account Hierarchy].[Account Group].[Expenditures],[Account].[Account Tree].[Account]), [Measures].[hasBudget] = 1)

select non empty
{ [Measures].[Rent] } on 0,

non empty
{ ([accounts] * (EXISTING [Asset].[asset].[All].children) * (EXISTING [Property].[Address].[All].children)) } on 1

from ( select { Filter([Asset].[asset].[All].children, [Measures].[hasBudget] = 1) } on 0

from ( select { Filter([Property].[Address].[All].children, [Measures].[hasBudget] = 1) } on 0

from [Master]))
```